# set flip animation for main menu item on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-animations

I have a demo website. how can I get the menu hover effect as in the reference website given below. I have fiddled little bit [here](https://jsfiddle.net/iamshajeer/e9bwL8Lv/1/), but I didn't get the transition when I hover on the menu item

ref site :- click [here](http://www.richardmille.com/)

hover on the top menu and see the effect. how do I get that effect ?

see the code here till I have done

**HTML**

```
<li>
    <div class="header-navigation-item-state-wrapper">
        <div class="white">
                <h4 class="header-white">Collections</h4>

        </div>
        <div class="black">
                <h4 class="header-black">Collections</h4>

        </div>
    </div>
</li>
```

**CSS**

```
* {
    background:yellow
}
li {
    list-style:none;
}
.header-black {
    background:#000;
    color:#fff;
    padding:10px;
    display:block
}
.black {
    display:none;
}
.header-white {
    background:#fff;
    color:#000;
    padding:10px;
    display:block
}
```

**JQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("li").mouseenter(function () {
        $(".white").css('display', 'none');
        $(".black").css('display', 'block');
    });
    $("li").mouseleave(function () {
        $(".white").css('display', 'block');
        $(".black").css('display', 'none');
    });
})
```

Comment: You haven't apply a single transition effect on mouseenter and mouseleave function, just display:none and display: block. It seems like your reference site's menu works by utilizing 3d-transform transition both to remove old and to add new element. Take look at anims here. http://www.createcss3.com/

Comment: @Miloshio dont have any idea on 3D animation, thats why I posted here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use 3d effect following way.

```css
.menu li {
 display: inline-block;
}

.menu li a {
 color: #fff;
 display: block;
 text-decoration: none;
 overflow: visible;
 line-height: 20px;
 font-size: 24px;
 padding: 15px 10px;
}

/* animation domination */
.threed {
 perspective: 200px;
 transition: all .07s linear;
 position: relative;
 cursor: pointer;
}
 /* complete the animation! */
 .threed:hover .box, 
 .threed:focus .box {
  transform: translateZ(-25px) rotateX(90deg);
 }

.box {
 transition: all .3s ease-out;
 transform: translatez(-25px);
 transform-style: preserve-3d;
 pointer-events: none;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 display: block;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}

.white {
 transform: rotatex(0deg) translatez(25px);
    background: white;
    color: black;
}

.black {
 transform: rotatex(-90deg) translatez(25px);
 color: white;
    background: black;
}

.white, .black {
 display: block;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 padding: 15px 10px;
 pointer-events: none;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="menu">
 <li><a href="/" class="threed">
  Home
  <span class="box">
   <span class="white">Home</span>
   <span class="black">Home</span>
  </span>
 </a></li>
</ul>
```

You can change as per your requirement. 
Hope it helps.